# Angular get current route defined, than undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-admin

I have this code:

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
```

Then:

```
constructor(router: Router) {
    console.log(this.router.url);
}
```

When I load the page, it will first tell me the URL is "/"

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Error in ./BaPageTop class BaPageTop - inline template:22:4 caused by: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined ;
```

I want to check if the current URL is equal to `/login`, and otherwise redirect to `"/login"` in the constructor. I tried doing this with window.location.href but it doesn't work because the URL is not changing parhaps?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: You need to use `router.events.subscribe(...)` and read the URL **after** the first navigation happened.

Comment: Okey, I will change the question

Answer (score 1):

Based on your constructor code, you never set `this.router` to anything, so it will always be `undefined`. By default, when you pass a parameter into a constructor, it does NOT become a property of `this`. You should change your code to:

```
constructor(router: Router) {
    console.log(router.url);
}
```

Alternatively, if you really want to use `this.router` (for example if you want to use the router in other functions in the same class), you can use the `public` or `private` keywords when you declare the parameter:

```
constructor(private router: Router) {
    console.log(this.router.url);
}
```